# Change precision of floats and export to csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Simple problem i guess.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': [1.2345, 2.3456, 1.3000], 'B': [1.2566, 3.5670, 6.7800]})

A        B
1,2345    1,2566
2,3456    3,5670
1,3000    6,7800
```

I actually just want to export the dataframe to a csv-file which looks like

```
A        B
1,235    1,26
2,346    3,57
1,300    6,78
```

I tried the following

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply('{:.3f}'.format)
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('float64')
df['B'] = df['B'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)
df['B'] = df['B'].astype('float64')
```

which displays fine in Jupyter. The exported file although misses the trailing zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float_format='%.2f'` parameter in [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv):

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', float_format='%.2f', index=False, sep='\t', decimal=',')
```

Will save CSV like:

```
A   B
1,23    1,26
2,35    3,57
1,30    6,78
```

---

EDIT:
To format Series `A` amd `B`, you can do:

```
tmp_df = df.copy()
tmp_df['A'] = tmp_df['A'].map(lambda x: '{:.03f}'.format(x).replace('.', ','))
tmp_df['B'] = tmp_df['B'].map(lambda x: '{:.02f}'.format(x).replace('.', ','))
tmp_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
```

This will save:

```
A   B
1,234   1,26
2,346   3,57
1,300   6,78
```

Comment: But _A_ should have 3 digits and _B_ 2.

Comment: @Paul Yes, you can then format it however you want. The parameter `float_format=` in `.to_csv()` will format all floats in DataFrame.